# Highcarts with zoomType + default level

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have set up a chart in Highcharts which utilises `zoomType: x`. I load in data over a long period of time (several months with hourly intervals). Is it possible to initially display the data over a shorter period of time, with a zoom out button that allows the user to view the full range?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) for that. It is way more appropriate than a simple `zoomType` if you want to navigate in the chart easily or setting default zoom when generating the chart.

See an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/data-grouping/) where the default zoom in 6 months but the actual range is 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can call setExtremes on xAxis and define your requested min / max values (zoom is based on setExtremes).

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

```
 chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 5);
```